Claculating angle of a line connecting parallel lines of a trapezoid, knowing their scale but not size
What I am trying to actually do is know how to rotate a 3D scaled extrusion in OpenSCAD so that the wall is parallel to Y axis. Something like this but here I just kept changing the angle so that it looks ok:

I know the height of the extrusion and the scale at which the bottom shape expands into the top one.
Thinking about this, I came to conclusion that I want to calculate angle A on this drawing:

s stands for my scale factor, and x is unknown or at least hard to calculate for different shapes. h then stands for the height over which the shape expands.
I refreshed my trigonometry knowledge and figured out I should calculate this:
$$tan{A} = \frac{x\times{s} - x}{h}\\
A = atan{\frac{x\times{s} - x}{h}}
$$
That does not seem to give the correct results at all. Also, I don't want to use x at all in the calculation. It seems that what I really want is actually an angle of a linear function $f(x) = x\times{s}$. The bottom dimensions should not matter and the angle should purely be function of h and s.
How do I calculate this needed rotation? It feels I almost arrived at the answer but can't quite figure the last step.
